# Is there some way to avoid HTML escaping of text children when calling React.createElement?

Tags: html, reactjs, html-escape-characters

Consider the following call to `React.createElement`:

```
React.createElement('span', null, null, ['&gt;&lt;',])
```

This will cause React to escape `&gt;` and `&lt;`. Is there some way to avoid this text being escaped?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```js
const Component = () => (
   <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '&gt;&lt;' }} />
);
 
ReactDOM.render(
   <Component />, document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

or use `Unicode codes` instead of HTML special characters

```js
const Component = () => (
  <span>{'\u003E\u003C'}</span>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />, document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine when need print a html header using `<pre>` and colored code, reactjs strip newlines.

Comment: This is a horribly insecure example. If you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML then please DOMPurify.sanitize this content!