# React 16 inject <style> into HTML header

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to inject CSS into the header which is first a string literal.

```
const HEAD_CSS = `
body {
  font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:21px;
  color:#444444;
}`
```

And after this, just:

```
return (
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">{HEAD_CSS}</style>
    </head>
      ... 
)
```

The problem is that after exporting that to HTML, I get the:

```
font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

line as:

```
`font-family:&#x27;Open Sans&#x27;, Arial, sans-serif;
```

The question is, how do keep the apostrophe instead of having `&#x27;`?

Comment: How are you exporting this to HTML? Managing HTML and HEAD tag with React seems weird to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some way to avoid HTML escaping of text children when calling React.createElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231902/is-there-some-way-to-avoid-html-escaping-of-text-children-when-calling-react-cre)