# How to change a chord in a <pre> tag to bold

Tags: regex

I have a string with chords like this

```
Bb
This is amazing grace   
Eb
This is unfailing love   
Gm
That You would take my place   
F
That You would bear my cross
```

I used regex to match and replace the chords with strong tag

```
const boldLyrics = lyrics?.replace(
    /(\b([CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|m|aug)*[\d\/]*(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:#|##|sus|maj|min|m|aug)*[\d\/]*)*)(?=\s|$)(?! \w))/gm,
    `<strong>$1</strong>`
);
```

and called it as `pre {boldLyrics} pre`

but it keeps on showing the texts like this.

```
<strong>Bb</strong>   
This is amazing grace
```

Comment: I am assuming it is JS/TS. Then, which framework are you using? Or, could you please give more code in the context?

Comment: Hi I am using ReactJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React.js/JSX,

> React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them ...(to help) ...prevent XSS (cross-site-scripting) attacks.

-- https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Here is how to prevent React from escaping the raw HTML:
[Is there some way to avoid HTML escaping of text children when calling React.createElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231902/is-there-some-way-to-avoid-html-escaping-of-text-children-when-calling-react-cre).

Do not forget to check the first link for advisory on potential XSS attack problems.